# SUM values on certain conditions

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table that is a summary of my actions for my clients and the time I've spent doing it.

So a row would look like this :

```
Client | Time |Week of the Year | Action
------------------------------------------
Client 1 | 1 | 1 | Summarize action 
Client 2 | 2| 1 | Summarize action
```

And I Would like to add a column (either a calculated column or a measure) that return the sum of time spent on the selected client for the selected week

So each row that contains `"client 1" && "Week 1"` show the total amount of time spent during "week 1" for `"client 1"` and I have no idea how to do that in powerbi ...

Comment: How are you trying to visualize your data? What you're asking for is possible without any custom measure or column. Are there multiple rows for the came client / week? (Ex a row with client 1, week 1, time 2 and another row with client 1, week 1, time 4)

Comment: Yes I do 1 row/action. The end goal is to visualize it in a Stacked bar char by slice (8h=1 slice) to be able to tell to my clients : "you're not utilizing your slices" or "you need to buy more slices"

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding [Client], [Week of the Year] and [Time] to a new table visual should do the trick. Just make sure that you're not summing the values of [Week of the Year], since it seems to be a numeric column from the example you posted:

[image]